# Tell Jest to use webpack loader when specifying within import statement

Tags: webpack, jestjs, webpack-2

I'm importing a JS module and telling Webpack to use a specific loader within my import

`import animate from 'babel-loader!animateplus';`

This works perfectly when loading the files on the client (browser). Webpack loads the `animateplus` module using the `babel-loader`.

However, when I'm importing this module in my tests (which are tested using `jest`), it fails because Jest doesn't understand how to load this module.

I'm getting the following error:

```
FAIL  src/blocks/HomePage/Recurring.client.test.js
   ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'babel-loader!animateplus' from 'Recurring.client.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:169:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/blocks/HomePage/Recurring.client.js:2:131)
```

Is there a way to tell Jest to load this module using a specific Webpack loader? Or would it better to mock this import?

Comment: Do you have installed `babel-jest` https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest

Comment: I don't think babel-jest will help in this case, since the exclamation mark syntax is something very webpack specific.

Comment: Correct @PatrickHund, that module didn't help.

Comment: I think your best bet is to get rid of the exclamation mark import statements and then simply use babel-jest, as described here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html

Comment: @Vernon did you solve it? I'm experiencing the same issue with https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader and Jest. 
"get rid of the exclamation mark import statements" is not an option for the time being.